# Python socket timeout and flush

Tags: python, ruby, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to translate this from Ruby to Python.
Ruby code:

```
def read_byte
    begin
        Timeout.timeout(0.5) do
            b = socket.read 1
        end
    rescue Timeout::Error => e
        socket.write("\n")
        socket.flush
        retry
    end
end

def socket
    @socket ||= TCPSocket.open @host, @port
rescue SocketError
    # TODO: raise a specific error
    raise "Unable to open connection to #{@host} with given parameters"
end
```

My mean problem here is with

> socket.flush

I can't find a way to do flush. what other way can I do this?
I wrote this.
Python code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((self.host, self.port))
s.settimeout(0.5)
while True:
    try:
        print s.recv(1)
    except socket.timeout:
        s.sendall("\n")
```

Comment: What would you expect flushing the socket to do that `sendall()` dosen't already do?

Comment: The stream is kinda hanging with my code. it's working with the Ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that flushing the socket will make a difference, but here is a way to "flush" the socket by first creating a file-like object.

```
def flush_socket(s):
    f = s.makefile()
    f.flush()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((self.host, self.port))
s.settimeout(0.5)
while True:
    try:
        print s.recv(1)
    except socket.timeout:
        s.sendall("\n")
        flush_socket(s)
```

Comment: It's still not receiving the same as the Ruby code. maybe it's another part of the ruby code or something.

Answer (score 0):

> The stream is kinda hanging with my code.

Of course it is, since it is an endless loop unless some exception other than `socket.timeout` occurs.

> maybe it's another part of the ruby code

It must be ... Inspect the Ruby loop where `read_byte` is called and compare that to your Python `while True`.

Comment: I haven't worked on this since two years ago. If you're interested you can see the updated [Ruby code](https://github.com/gareth/live_f1-core) and my [Python code](https://github.com/dadoeyad/live-f1-py)

Comment: In _the updated Ruby code_ `read_bytes num` in *live_f1-core / lib / live_f1 / source / live.rb* tries to read only `num` bytes compared to infinitely many with the Python `while True`.